# Firebase authentication asp.net core

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, jwt, firebase-authentication

After a successful sign-in to Firebase we received a JWT token.

In order to add authorization to my asp.net app, I tried to add a JwtBearerAuthentication to my middleware.

I have tried the following JwtBearerOptions:

```
 var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Audience = "myApp",
            Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com"
        };
```

and

```
 var options = new JwtBearerOptions
        {
            Audience = "myApp",
            Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/myApp"
        };
```

Unfortunately this is not working. My Authority URL is probably incorrect.

Does anyone know which Authority URL is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JWT validation need to be manual : [source](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens)

The following code is validating the FirebaseToken (JWT) :

```
    //Download certificates from google
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var jsonResult = client.GetStringAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com").Result;

    //Convert JSON Result
    var x509Metadata = JObject.Parse(jsonResult)
                        .Children()
                        .Cast<JProperty>()
                        .Select(i => new x509Metadata(i.Path, i.Value.ToString()));

    //Extract IssuerSigningKeys
    var issuerSigningKeys = x509Metadata.Select(s => s.X509SecurityKey);

    //Setup JwtTokenHandler 
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken token;
    handler.ValidateToken(user.FirebaseToken, new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        IssuerSigningKeys = issuerSigningKeys,
        ValidAudience = "myApp",
        ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/myApp",
        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (arbitrarily, declaring, these, parameters) => issuerSigningKeys
    }, out token);

public class x509Metadata
{
    public string KID { get; set; }
    public string Certificate { get; set; }
    public X509SecurityKey X509SecurityKey { get; set; }

    public x509Metadata(string kid, string certificate)
    {
        KID = kid;
        Certificate = certificate;
        X509SecurityKey = BuildSecurityKey(Certificate);
    }

    private X509SecurityKey BuildSecurityKey(string certificate)
    {
        //Remove : -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- & -----END CERTIFICATE-----
        var lines = certificate.Split('\n');
        var selectedLines = lines.Skip(1).Take(lines.Length - 3);
        var key = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, selectedLines);

        return new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(key)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase publishes JWKs with standard format here:

https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com

(though they don't mention it in the docs)

I found this information here: https://github.com/cfworker/cfworker/issues/89#issuecomment-748422827

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30363536)