# ASP.NET Core API how to manually authorize an user

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core API with an Action that has an `Authorize` attribute.

This API talks to an Firebase authenticated Ionic application. When I login in the client application, I get an authorization token that I send to the API with every endpoint call.

The API gets this token and then validates with Firebase. Now I have a boolean telling me that this request is authenticated or not.

Is there any way to somehow inform the controller that this call should be processed without removing the `Authorize` attribute from the action?

Comment: Sounds like you need some middleware added that will handle this. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190512/firebase-authentication-asp-net-core

Answer (score 1):

If someone come across this in the future, I solved the problem creating a custom middleware, based on this:

http://www.mithunvp.com/write-custom-asp-net-core-middleware-web-api/

I send the token in the HTTP request header, then the middleware intercepts every call to the API and validates the token. If it's valid, the call is processed normally, if not, the request is cancelled and the call doesn't even get to the API endpoint.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Please add the answer here. Also, the link is dead now.