# Is it possible to incorporate Firebase Auth into ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase, asp.net-core, firebase-authentication

I am working to build an Ionic mobile application, and I plan to use Firebase's auth and realtime database offerings. I am trying to understand if it's possible to also incorporate Firebase auth into the server-side processing within an associated ASP.NET Core MVC site. This would allow me to use some 'static' server-side pages to handle subscriptions, payments, etc but still leverage the same Firebase-based user scheme as the mobile app.

I know Firebase is geared towards javascript clients, and I found [this example of authenticating a request that includes an `Authorization` header within an API](https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/) within asp.net core, so it's possible to validate a firebase token in the asp.net pipeline. However, this assumes a javascript client is making all requests, and I'd like to instead have the token stored in some cookie that I can have the browser seamlessly provide. This would let me handle authentication on static, non-javascript pages within my app.

I'm thinking there must be some way to initiate authentication against firebase, and have the response redirected to an MVC action. Then you could presumably set an "indentity" cookie within asp.net that would persist across page refreshes. Or am I just way off base on my understanding of how this works?

**Comment on possible duplicate of [Firebase authentication asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190512/firebase-authentication-asp-net-core):**

This is not a dupe in my opinion because that question is talking about verifying a JWT token provided by a client (presumably javascript). I believe the link I included originally demonstrates a way to solve that problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase authentication asp.net core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190512/firebase-authentication-asp-net-core)

Comment: Updated to comment on the possible duplicate, and re-worded it to hopefully be more clear what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

In the login method, you can create a firebase session cookie and add the cookie in the response. For example

```
   var sessionCookie = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance
        .CreateSessionCookieAsync(request.IdToken, options);

    // Set cookie policy parameters as required.
    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions()
    {
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(options.ExpiresIn),
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true,
    };
    this.Response.Cookies.Append("session", sessionCookie, cookieOptions);
```

With this, you can then fetch that cookie in other requests you send to the servers. May it be simple page load request without any js involved. Instead of verifying in every request, a better approach would be to overide the native authorize attribute and instead provide your custom implementation that verifies that session cookie is still valid or otherwise redirects to the login.

```
var sessionCookie = this.Request.Cookies["session"];
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sessionCookie))
{
    // Session cookie is not available. Force user to login.
    return this.Redirect("/login");
}

try
{
    // Verify the session cookie. In this case an additional check is added to detect
    // if the user's Firebase session was revoked, user deleted/disabled, etc.
    var checkRevoked = true;
    var decodedToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifySessionCookieAsync(
        sessionCookie, checkRevoked);
    return ViewContentForUser(decodedToken);
}
```

If you don't want to sign in the user using the client SDK at all, you also have the option to use the method signInWithCustomToken while you generate the custom token on server side using CreateCustomTokenAsync which accepts the UID of the user. Let me know if you have any questions.